# NGINX/SWAG: Rewrite URL to remove .php extension

Tags: php, nginx, url, url-rewriting

there are dozens of similar question in the internet (stackoverflow and other sites), but none of them worked for me.
I am trying to rewrite my URL to get rid of the .php extension at the end. I already tried the common rewrites in my config.
I hope somebody knows an answer i did not use yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your vhost config file or nginx.conf file, add the following lines in the inside server block :

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    index index.html index.htm index.php; }

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404; }

location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last; }
```

Need to restart Nginx before use.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I already tried that, but of course i did it again. Sadly it still doesnt work. Always "404 not foud". Shouldnt the 404 intercepted by " try_files $uri =404;" ?

Comment: Correction: My SWAG Setup was trash. I recreated everything with a nice setup and now it works with you code. You have to add it under /swag/config/nginx/site-confs/default. BUT watch out! You cant have multiple standard location blocks there. So just delete the one, that was already there.

Answer (score 0):

you can use .htaccess

make a new file in the directory which your PHP files are there, make a new file called `.htaccess`, put in the following in there:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/*\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I already tried that, but of course i did it again, but sadly it doesnt work. I think something has to be completly wrong in my config :(